# Unparseable Date Exception SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, simpledateformat, timezone-offset

While parsing string to date object using `SimpleDateFormat`, I am getting below error.

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue, 29 Mar 2016 11:27:37 -0400"

The code I am using to parsed date is:

```
DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
```

**I am able to parse dates like `Mon, 13 Jun 2016 11:48:54 +0300`**.

I noticed one thing that dates having `+ve` timezone(+0300) are getting parsed but `-ve` timezone(-0400) are not getting parsed.

Comment: Could be a "non regular" `-` like &ndash; or [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is that your default locale is not English (maybe German, which would explain why Mon works (Montag) but not Tue (Dienstag)?).

Just specify ENGLISH as a locale:

```
DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = df2.parse("Tue, 29 Mar 2016 11:27:37 -0400");
System.out.println(date); //prints Tue Mar 29 15:27:37 GMT 2016
```

The code  above works fine [on ideone](http://ideone.com/GbeP1F) and on my machine.

Comment: And its not like Mon or Tues because I am getting error for all days in a week. The common thing I noticed is only -ve timezone.

Comment: @user2779095 The solution I suggest works fine with the input in your question: http://ideone.com/GbeP1F - can you show a [mcve]? What version of Java are you running?

Comment: i am using jdk1.6.0_21 version.

Comment: One more thing. I am parsing dates like "24 Mar 2016 22:58:29 +1100" and "27 Mar 2016 15:55:54 -0700" 
Using DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
It is getting parsed without any issue.

Comment: @user2779095 can you paste the code that doesn't work in your question (all of it, including the input and the formatter)? I can't reproduce your problem (cf ideone link)...

Comment: You have to format it.  
for (Message msg : msgs)

{
 Enumeration headers = msg.getAllHeaders();
 Date msgGetReceivedDate = new Date();
 DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
 String temp="";
 while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
 Header h = (Header) headers.nextElement();
  if(h.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Date"))
  {
   temp  = h.getValue();
  }
 }
 msgGetReceivedDate=df2.parse(temp.trim());               
}

Comment: @user2779095 You are still not showing the input! Your problem may be that `msgs` does not contain what you think it does. Unless you build a [mcve] it is difficult to help you!